# How can I get some idea of how much a cracked foundation would cost to fix?

Tags: repair, foundation, structural

I can't get a structural engineer to evaluate this because the housing market is too active here. Does this sort of thing seem fixable? Am I looking at like $50k to fix something like this?

The house is priced far below market, so I think ultimately I could make some gains out of this. But I'm also worried I might find out that it's not fixable, or that it costs a huge amount to fix. Then it could turn out a nightmare.

https://imgur.com/a/nJlJotE

Comment: Too little information to make any guesses as to the cause/remediation, and pricing requests/info is off-limits in this forum, especially with it being a global group and you've given no location information).  But in general, if a house is priced far below market, there's a good reason for it (especially in this mostly still hot housing market), and if the cost is unknown, then likely it's a lot more than the seller wanted to put into it to sell, which means it's probably going to be a rather expensive repair, as most foundation repairs get very expensive quite quickly.

Comment: What's the age of the house? Is that the only crack like that? Are there lots of smaller cracks? I would keep looking for the cause of the low price, because this doesn't look like the deal breaker.

Comment: The price to fix it in _your_ neighborhood is going to be different than the price to fix it in _my_ neighborhood. Oh, and it'll be different next month to say nothing of next year. That's why pricing questions are off-topic.

Comment: A general contractor or foundation  specialist who's been around for a while could probably give you at least a ballpark estimate, since they've probably fixed a bunch of these.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that no person who knows what they are doing are going to agree to spend several hours coming up with an estimate, when you don't even own the house. You might as well ask for a $500 handout. And no one can give you a realistic estimate without looking at it in person. Fixing a foundation is a lot more than just looking at the damage, but figuring out access. Something in front of the house with easy access and no buried utilities is going to be a fraction of the cost of say, fixing a foundation in the rear part of the house with no path to bringing equipment in.

This type of house purchase is for people who can quickly assess costs from just looking at it, based on experience. In other words, it's a speculative purchase, better left to experienced speculators.

I'm all for buying fixer uppers; you just need to work your way up, starting with houses with cosmetic damage (drywall, siding, floors, tile, etc.), then as you accumulate experience, go up to structural issues, eg roofs, sagging floors, foundations, etc.

Comment: Please don't answer blatantly off-topic questions... ;)